# How to get total values in a moving window in a raster, with another raster as reference for center of windows

Tags: r, terra

I have a raster which is a mask with 0,1 values for presence/absence of a young forest.

Another raster is also a mask with 0,1 values for presence/absence of old forests.

Given a window of adjustable width (range) around each young forest cell, I'd like to know how many cells in the window are old forests.

I tried to use the focal function to create a moving window over all cells in the mature forest raster, but as my rasters are very large, it was becoming too computationally intensive.

```
> mature_mask
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 31734, 16026, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.0002694946, 0.0002694946  (x, y)
extent      : -48.31876, -43.99984, -3.282444, 5.269697  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source(s)   : memory
name        : classification_2019 
min value   :                   0 
max value   :                   1 

range <- 21
mature_sum <- focal(mature_mask, range, sum, na.rm = TRUE) # run focal on these areas
```

The code takes about 7 minutes to run for a buffer size of 21 with the "sum" function, but if I try a buffer size of 101 with the "mean" function it becomes too much for my computer to handle ("bad::alloc" error comes up, which I believe is a memory issue?)

I am trying to restrain the values so I only need to calculate the total counts for the cells in the surroundings the secondary forests (consider both rasters to be sparse).

I tried to determine the surrounding area around each secondary forest patch so I'd be able to mask the old forest raster reduce the amount of calculation needed.

```
rm <- matrix(0, 6, 6)
young <- rast(rm)
young[1] <- 1
young[15] <- 1

old <- rast(rm)
old[2] <- 1
old[16] <- 1
old[14] <- 1


young_surroundings <- buffer(young, 20)
```

And I thought of masking old with young_surroundings before running focal to reduce computational time, but buffer also seems to be time consuming.

My ideal outcome would be a raster old_sum which would look like

```
old_sum <- young
old_sum[1] <- 1
old_sum[15] <- 2 # total of surrounding old forest patches
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not show what you tried --- that makes it difficult to help, as it is not clear *what* you did that took too long.

So let me first suggest the vanilla solution that should be pretty fast:

First fixing your example data (forest cannot be old *and* young)

```
old <- rm2
young <- ifel(old, NA, rm)
```

Now use focal

```
# create a circular window consisting of zeros and ones
m <- focalMat(old, 3, 'circle')
m[m>0] <- 1

# use focal
f <- focal(old, m, sum, na.rm=TRUE)

# and mask
x <- mask(f, young)
```

Comment: Sorry I should have explained better. I have tried running focal on the entire old forest raster, as you did here, but the raster contains millions of cells so this takes too much memory. My intent was to reduce the amount of calculations necessary, as I only need the sum of values that are around young forests, so I'd need to do some sort of masking before running focal to spend time computing only the values that are important. I have tried to do this with indices ((multiple_i+k)*ncol(rm)+(remainder_j-range) and so on) as I wrote above, but that is also very time consuming

Comment: so would there be a way to mask the old forest raster before running focal, so we get the sum only around secondary forests and avoid doing unnecessary calculations?

Comment: No you cannot. But please do edit your question and `show(x)` where `x` is your real raster and show how you run focal. millions of cells should not be a problem

Comment: I hope I've explained better now. I'll try to run again and see, but everything else seems to be running normally in my lab's computer. Thank you so much for everything!

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got the issue. I'm trying to run focal with a large window and the mean function, which is slower than sum. I'll try to work my way around this so it runs faster. Will comment here if I'm successful